# How to display Manifest, Application, Permissions Tabs in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I wanna add the Manifest, Application, Permissions Tabs in Android Studio. I have searched a lot for the options but couldn't locate option to display those tabs.

In this image, you can see how the tabs are laid out in Eclipse. I'd like to have the same layout in Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio does not have this feature.

Comment: So should I go for Eclipse? Does it support?

Comment: No, you shouldn't go for Eclipse. These tabs only provide an alternative view on the contents of your Android manifest file. You can accomplish everything you need by editing the manifest file as text, which Android Studio fully supports.